# Deploy SQL changes along with war file

Tags: java, sql, deployment

Our developers want to execute some DB scripts along with Java code which has dependency with DB scripts. So they have a class called "DatabaseUpgrader" which executes at server startup and look for particular folder. The folder contains SQL files which follows sequence. So no issues when we have few developers, but when number of developers increase and number of parallel development involved we face some issues.

Is there any best way to deploy SQL and WAR files at same time with out any issues?

Comment: use a `version control system` for the database scripts also

Comment: Check out Liquibase or Flyway.

Comment: @Farhęg We user version control, It works this way. We have sequence of SQL files like 1.sql,2.sql...etc. While startup execute the SQL and store the version in DB. When we deploy next time we just look for next sequence number. So developers have to maintain the sequence properly.